# window.onload is not working after Response.AppendHeader

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a loading image which is working fine 
but when  I add a download button to the form and 
added  code

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ssss.xls");
        Response.WriteFile(uploadingFilePath & fileName)
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

and I understood that when runs

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ssss.xls");
```

line ,then the `window.onload` functions is not working 
can anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.onload` is a javascript function. The response you are writing now is an excel file.

When you set the `ContentType` http header, you tell the browser that you are sending it an application file, and the browser will prompt the user to save the file to disk.

Your page, and your javascript does not receive an events when the user is prompted or the file downloads.

There is no way to remove the loading image on an event if your response is a file.
You could remove it by setting a javascript `setTimeOut`.

Refer: [setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

This will call the function `hideImage` after 5 seconds. Add it to your function that shows the image.

```
function hideImage() {
    //hide your image
}
window.setTimeout(hideImage, 5000);
```

Comment: if i give settimeout then in which event that i have to use

Comment: thank you very much your answer is very helpful as well as informative to me once again thank you and it worked also